# Nginx - After added server_name all the urls are showing 404

Tags: nginx, https, centos

I have a Nginx server which hosts only one website in port 80. I wanted to do SSL with lets encrypt, so I have added my domain name in the server_name section.

```
server_name localhost; 
to
server_name my-domain.in www.my-domain.in
```

Then I checked the Nginx conf check, everything was normal, once I did nginx reload, then I couldn't access the website. All the urls are showing 404.

Then I reverted the `server_name` to `localhost`. Now its working. But  I want to add my domain name there without any errors.

Can anyone guide on this? and why it showed 404?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you ping your server with its "proper" DNS name. If not you may have a DNS lookup problem.
2. HTTPS pages are typically served on port 443. Did you configure your server to output on this port?
3. Is the log file on your server showing the attempted access on port 80?

Comment: 1. My DNS is working fine, verified. 2. Right now im trying to fixe server_name in listen 80 section.

Comment: Is your server logging an access request?